# Error on debug.log PHP Stric Standards and PHP notice

Tags: debug

I'm getting this error on the `debug.log` but I don't know why. WordPress and all of the plugins are on their latest versions. So, I don't know if this is normal or no.

```
 PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in     suggested_achievements_widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0!     
 Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /home/content/.../wp-includes/functions.php on line 3891
 PHP Strict Standards:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method bphelp_remove_profile_links::remove_xprofile_links() should not be called statically in /home/content/..../wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 298
```

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly turn it off with

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

or reduce errors.

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
```

however you might want to use the information to make changes to the code